# File upload to s3 using HTML form not working

Tags: amazon-s3

```
<form action="https://bucketname-sellercentral.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">              
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}">
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="GGGGGGGGGG46IITQQ"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://192.168.1.4:8443/test">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value=<policy>
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value=<signature>
    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">


  <input name="file" type="file" >
```

```
</form>
```

Here if in the key field i put value="uploads/tulips.jpg" it works but if i do not specify the filename it is not working ie value="uploads/${filename}" does not work

it does not throw an error or exception is simply is not visible in my s3 bucket

Comment: Did you actually include the values for `<signature>` and `policy` in your form? You need to follow the instructions to generate both of these values: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

Comment: I also assume you're using your real AWS Access key. Double check all these values.